# Why I can't calculate the distance between a fixed point and a geometry field of a MySql table using this distance function?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, spatial, geometry

I am not so into database and GIS and I have the following problem.

I have defined this function that return the distance between 2 points in the space represented by 2 **point** fields:

```
CREATE FUNCTION earth_circle_distance(point1 point, point2 point) RETURNS double
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
  declare lon1, lon2 double;
  declare lat1, lat2 double;
  declare td double;
  declare d_lat double;
  declare d_lon double;
  declare a, c, R double;

  set lon1 = X(GeomFromText(AsText(point1)));
  set lon2 = X(GeomFromText(AsText(point2)));
  set lat1 = Y(GeomFromText(AsText(point1)));
  set lat2 = Y(GeomFromText(AsText(point2)));

  set d_lat = radians(lat2 - lat1);
  set d_lon = radians(lon2 - lon1);

  set lat1 = radians(lat1);
  set lat2 = radians(lat2);

  set R = 6372.8; -- in kilometers

  set a = sin(d_lat / 2.0) * sin(d_lat / 2.0) + sin(d_lon / 2.0) * sin(d_lon / 2.0) * cos(lat1) * cos(lat2);
  set c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));

  return R * c;
end
```

It works pretty fine, I tryied passing to it 2 point defined by:

```
SET @point1= GeomFromText('POINT(41.772683, 12.241714)'); 
SET @point2 = GeomFromText('POINT(42.1212121, 13.1212121)');
```

The problem is that  I want to use this fucntion into a query to calculate the distance between a setted point and another point represented by a record of my **accomodation** table.

So I have tryied something like this:

```
SET @fiumicino = GeomFromText('POINT(41.772683, 12.241714)'); 

SELECT a.accomodation_name as name, 
       AsText(a.geographical_position) as position,
       X(a.geographical_position) as lat,
       Y(a.geographical_position) as lon,
       earth_circle_distance(@fiumicino, a.geographical_position)
FROM accomodation a
```

I want to calculate the distance of all the points represented by the **geographical_position** field of the **accomodation** table and the setted point **@fiumicino**.

The data type of the **geographical_position** field is **GEOMETRY** (because in Java I have some problem to interact with **POINT** data type using Hibernate, I can't change it).

The problem is that performing the previous query is that I obtain the following error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`(a.geographical_position)`, `@Y(a.geographical_position)`, earth_circle_d' at line 3

The problem happens when the **earth_circle_distance(@fiumicino, a.geographical_position)** is performed.

Infact deleting this statment from my query, so performing this simplified query that don't calculate the ditance:

```
SET @fiumicino = GeomFromText('POINT(41.772683, 12.241714)'); 

SELECT a.accomodation_name as name, 
       AsText(a.geographical_position) as position,
       X(a.geographical_position) as lat,
       Y(a.geographical_position) as lon
FROM accomodation a

name                            position                    lat                     lon 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Grand Hotel Marina de Ostia     POINT(41.729086 12.278478)  41.729086               12.278478
Motel La Bettola                POINT(41.883991 12.33544)   41.883991               12.33544
HOTEL 1                         POINT(41.82703258287677     12.266217163303374)     41.82703258287677   12.266217163303374
HOTEL 2                         POINT(41.816297452855096 12.239581452630633)        41.816297452855096  12.239581452630633
```

So, as you can see, the value of **a.geographical_position** field used into **earth_circle_distance(@fiumicino, a.geographical_position)** is something like **POINT(41.883991 12.33544)**. But int this way it didn't work.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing?

I also retrived the value of the **latitude** and of the **longitude** of my point, by **@X(a.geographical_position)** and **@Y(a.geographical_position)**.

If I knew how, I could create a new point with the previous values as  second parameter to pass to this **earth_circle_distance()** function.
How do I obtain the distance between the fixed point and the point represented by the **a.geographical_position** of the current record?

Comment: Just from a quick scan of your question, try the following.  define your POINT for @fiumicino without the `,`.  `POINT(41.772683 12.241714)`.  Make sure you don't get LAT and LON mixed up.  In the function you are setting LAT to Y (correct) and in the query select clause you are aliasing X to LAT.  [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56f78/1424) of point definition

Comment: Why is this tagged postgis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is just complaining because there is no `@Y()` function, it's just `ST_Y` (preferred) or `Y()` (older crap)